# SQL geting Top X number of rows

Tags: sql, rows

i want to get only the top x number of the query. where the x will be send by parameter how can i do this?

I know i can take it as string and exec it later but i find it very cumbersome.

This the query i have and @ArticleNo is the parameter i want to take as x.

```
Create proc [dbo].[GW2_Report_SlowFastMovingArticle]    

@ArtKey bigint = null,
@ArtCatKey int= null,
@ArtGroupKey int= null,
@ArtTypeKey int= null,
@MaterialKey int= null,
@ColorKey int= null,
@VendorTypeKey int = null,
@VendorKey bigint = null,
@FromDate datetime = null,
@ToDate datetime = null,
@MovingType int = 0,
@PerformanceType int = 0,
@ArticleNo int = 10,
@OutletKey int = null
AS    
BEGIN  

SELECT 
dbo.Sal_POSDet.ArtKey,
dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtCode, 
dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtName,
Sum(isnull(dbo.Sal_POSDet.Qty,0))as Pair,
Sum(isnull(dbo.Sal_POSDet.Total,0)) as TurnOver
into #temp FROM 
dbo.Sal_POS INNER JOIN
dbo.Sal_POSDet ON 
dbo.Sal_POS.SalesKey = dbo.Sal_POSDet.SalesKey INNER JOIN
dbo.ArtWithVendor ON 
dbo.Sal_POSDet.ArtKey = dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtKey

WHERE

Sal_POS.IsHold=0 and
Sal_POS.SalesDate between @FromDate  and @ToDate  and
        CASE WHEN  @ArtKey  is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtKey =@ArtKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1   
        and CASE WHEN @ArtCatKey  is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtCatKey =@ArtCatKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @ArtGroupKey is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtGroupKey = @ArtGroupKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @ArtTypeKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtTypeKey = @ArtTypeKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @MaterialKey is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.MaterialKey = @MaterialKey  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @ColorKey  is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ColorKey = @ColorKey  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @VendorKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.VendorKey = @VendorKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @VendorTypeKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.VendorTypeKey = @VendorTypeKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @OutLetKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN Sal_POS.OutLetKey = @OutLetKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     

Group by 

dbo.Sal_POSDet.ArtKey,
dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtCode, 
dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtName



if(@PerformanceType=0 and @MovingType=0)
begin
select * from #temp 
order by Pair asc
end
if(@PerformanceType=0 and @MovingType=1)
begin
select  * from #temp 
order by Pair desc
end
if(@PerformanceType=1 and @MovingType=0)
begin
select * from #temp 
order by turnover asc
end
if(@PerformanceType=1 and @MovingType=1)
begin
select * from #temp 
order by turnover desc
end

END
```

Comment: is that one helpful? http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/070605-1.shtml

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server is this for?

Comment: @Taufiq: your accepted answer is *dangerous*. Use rjdevereux's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT TOP(@ArticleNo)
```

Therefore:

```
SELECT TOP(@ArticleNo)
    dbo.Sal_POSDet.ArtKey,
    dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtCode, 
    dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtName,
    Sum(isnull(dbo.Sal_POSDet.Qty,0))as Pair,
    Sum(isnull(dbo.Sal_POSDet.Total,0)) as TurnOver
    into #temp FROM 
    dbo.Sal_POS INNER JOIN
    dbo.Sal_POSDet ON 
    dbo.Sal_POS.SalesKey = dbo.Sal_POSDet.SalesKey INNER JOIN
    dbo.ArtWithVendor ON 
    dbo.Sal_POSDet.ArtKey = dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtKey

    WHERE

    Sal_POS.IsHold=0 and
    Sal_POS.SalesDate between @FromDate  and @ToDate  and
            CASE WHEN  @ArtKey  is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtKey =@ArtKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1   
            and CASE WHEN @ArtCatKey  is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtCatKey =@ArtCatKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
            and CASE WHEN @ArtGroupKey is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtGroupKey = @ArtGroupKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
            and CASE WHEN @ArtTypeKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtTypeKey = @ArtTypeKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
            and CASE WHEN @MaterialKey is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.MaterialKey = @MaterialKey  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
            and CASE WHEN @ColorKey  is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ColorKey = @ColorKey  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
            and CASE WHEN @VendorKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.VendorKey = @VendorKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
            and CASE WHEN @VendorTypeKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.VendorTypeKey = @VendorTypeKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
            and CASE WHEN @OutLetKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN Sal_POS.OutLetKey = @OutLetKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     

    Group by 

    dbo.Sal_POSDet.ArtKey,
    dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtCode, 
    dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtName
```

---

Alternatively, add the following before your `SELECT` query:

```
IF @ArticleNo IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   SET ROWCOUNT @ArticleNo
END
```

Then after your `SELECT` query you need to reset the `ROWCOUNT` by doing:

```
IF @ArticleNo IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
    SET ROWCOUNT 0
 END
```

---

Therefore, overall it will be something like:

```
   IF @ArticleNo IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
       SET ROWCOUNT @ArticleNo
    END


SELECT 
dbo.Sal_POSDet.ArtKey,
dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtCode, 
dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtName,
Sum(isnull(dbo.Sal_POSDet.Qty,0))as Pair,
Sum(isnull(dbo.Sal_POSDet.Total,0)) as TurnOver
into #temp FROM 
dbo.Sal_POS INNER JOIN
dbo.Sal_POSDet ON 
dbo.Sal_POS.SalesKey = dbo.Sal_POSDet.SalesKey INNER JOIN
dbo.ArtWithVendor ON 
dbo.Sal_POSDet.ArtKey = dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtKey

WHERE

Sal_POS.IsHold=0 and
Sal_POS.SalesDate between @FromDate  and @ToDate  and
        CASE WHEN  @ArtKey  is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtKey =@ArtKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1   
        and CASE WHEN @ArtCatKey  is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtCatKey =@ArtCatKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @ArtGroupKey is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtGroupKey = @ArtGroupKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @ArtTypeKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ArtTypeKey = @ArtTypeKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @MaterialKey is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.MaterialKey = @MaterialKey  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @ColorKey  is null THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.ColorKey = @ColorKey  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @VendorKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.VendorKey = @VendorKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @VendorTypeKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN ArtWithVendor.VendorTypeKey = @VendorTypeKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     
        and CASE WHEN @OutLetKey  is null  THEN 1 WHEN Sal_POS.OutLetKey = @OutLetKey THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1     

Group by 

dbo.Sal_POSDet.ArtKey,
dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtCode, 
dbo.ArtWithVendor.ArtName

IF @ArticleNo IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
    SET ROWCOUNT 0
 END
```

However using `ROWCOUNT` is not ideal as it will mess with your sub-query results.

Comment: Thing you misunderstood me i want to query to return some number of top row where some number with be send through parameter in my query @ArticleNo

Comment: @Taufiq I've ammended my answer to use the `@ArticleNo` parameter

Comment: -1 for suggesting ROWCOUNT. It buggers your intermediate and subqueries results

Comment: Cheers @gbn - I never thought of that. In this case, there are no sub-queries, so I think it's fine? But obviously its not as future proof. Is `SELECT TOP(@ArticleNo)` different to `SELECT TOP @ArticleNo`? In the past I've had errors with the 2nd query.

Comment: Using () makes is required to parameterise TOP. This was added in SQL Server 2005 (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170355%28SQL.90%29.aspx). With constants, you can omit () but this is backwards compatibility only. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Also I'd use TOP as best practice anyway

Comment: @gbn Cheers again, I've never been a fan of `ROWCOUNT`, I just didn't know about `TOP()`! I'll ammend my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
select TOP(@ArticleNo) * 
from #temp
```