# Selecting a number of rows with TOP based on expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to break the table into 2 parts. (SQL Server 2017)
this is my code:

```
 SELECT TOP COUNT(*)/2 TargetColumn
 FROM SomeTable
```

The error message is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'COUNT'

TOP doesn't allow me to do that. expressions using fixed numbers aka 2000/2 works, but the above one using COUNT does not.

I have searched StackOverflow but have found only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410126/sql-geting-top-x-number-of-rows) post that is relevant, which has 2 answers, one of which was branded "dangerous", and the second one I did not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in a single query, you need to get the rowcount and then use that for your `top` query e.g.

```
DECLARE @NumRows INT;

SELECT @NumRows = COUNT(*)/2
FROM SomeTable;

SELECT TOP(@NumRows) TargetColumn
FROM SomeTable;
```

This is because [`TOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a simple function designed to limit the number of rows returned. Having to count the rows requires all rows to be returned which is a contradiction.

If you wish to perform this operation in a single query please see @GMB's answer.

For the table I tested on, this solution took 28% and GMB's took 72% without an order by. If you add an order by this solution took 52% and GMB's took 48%. So the best performing query depends on your specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single query using window functions:

```
select targetcolumn
from (
    select 
        targetcolumn, 
        row_number() over(order by somecol) rn,
        count(*) over() cnt
    from sometable
) t
where rn <= cnt / 2
```

The subquery performs a window `count()` of all records in the table, and ranks records with `row_number()`. Then, the outer query filters on the bottom half.

Note that using `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` clause does not really make sense: the ordering of the records is inherently undefined unless explicitly specified, so this results in an undefined set of rows being returned (although with a fixed number of records). I assumed that you have a column for ordering, and called it `somecol` in the above query.

Comment: hi, unfortunately I didn't get this to work, got the same message about incorrect syntax near COUNT.I already accepted Dale's answer as he was first and the code worked though, so maybe you won't wish to look into why yours isn't running ok.   Thank you for trying anyway, much appreciate such quick responses.

Comment: @LanaB there was a single comma (',') missing from this answer after `rn` which I have added.